# What is the formula for loan payoff with daily compounded interest and monthly payment?

Tags: loans, interest, payment, amortization, principal

My goal is to make a graph using this formula for all possible monthly payments.

Let's say...

```
Loans: 21750
Monthly Payment: 220
Daily Interest: 4.0% / 365
```

What formula would I use to get the total amount of money (or Principal) I'd use to pay off this loan at this rate?

Comment: keyword: "loan amortization"

Comment: At 4% DAILY that debt more than doubles each month. There is no way to pay it back with given monthly payment.

Comment: @Ghanima excuse me but all internet rates in the market are quoted at nominal (annualized) basis. You divide 4% by 365 to get daily.

Comment: The rate appears annual obviously. OP meant compounded daily.

Comment: @Ghanima Thanks for catching that, I did mean 4% annual but compounded daily.

Comment: @base64, while it might be implied it was not what it read pre-edit. I am always under the impression that in law and finance you better stick to the letter...

Comment: @Ghanima in law and finance you exercise common sense and be aware of something known as "usury limit" where 4% per day is absolutely not honored in court. See http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-there-a-law-or-regulation-that-governs-the-maximum-allowable-interest-amount for EU, US, Canada terms.

Comment: @base64, yes, I am well aware that this would be "usury" (great, new vocab ^^) in countries that provide such legislation. But what do we know which country the OP is refering to? However stated as "per annum" it removes all ambiguity.

Comment: @Ghanima it is the US. Move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the compounding period and payment period differs (Compounded Daily vs Paid Monthly), you need to find the effective interest rate for one payment period (month).

[image]

This means that each month you pay 0.33387092772% of the outstanding principal as interest.

Then use this formula to find the number of months:

[image]

Where PV = 21750, Pmt = 220, i = 0.0033387092772

[image]

That gives 120 Months.

Depending on the day count convention, (30/360 or 30.416/365 or Actual/Actual), the answer may differ slightly. Using Financial Calculator gives extremely similar answer.

**The total cash paid in the entire course of the loan is 120 x $220 = $26,400**

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! Although I am quite curious to why ln is used. Can you explain the meaning of that?

Comment: @Vongdarakia It is "Natural Log". It is a button on most calculators. ln(y) gives the x in the equation 2.71828^x=y, where 2.71828 is a mathematical constant.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Also, 26,400 doesn't seem to be the exact amount. Would it make sense to calculate the total amount like this? total = total - (nMonths - wholeMonths) * monthlyPayment? i.e. 26400 - (120.184399 - 120) * 220 = 26359.43. Since the 0.184399 looks to be the overpayment.

Comment: @Vongdarakia I'd say it is reasonable but 120.18 is just an approximation. Sometimes there are 366 days in a year, sometimes a month is not 30 days, but 31 or 29 or 28.